# Redirecting an unauthorized user in identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, authorize-attribute

For my mvc5 project i have implemented default identity but changed it according to requirements. Now i wanted to redirect unauthorized users to an view which has been created by me. I created a custom authorize filter. When an unauthorized user enters it comes to my error view. I can recognize it by the URL. But the problem is it is not showing the content in the view. Instead it is showing HTTP 404 error. I have put my code below. I know this has been asked here several times. But still i couldn't solve it. All help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
            RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Error", action = "AccessDenied" }));
        }
    }
}
```

ErrorController

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    // GET: Error
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AccessDenied()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

AccessDenied view

```
<h2>AccessDenied</h2>

Access Denied
```

On a particular controller

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class ProductTypeController : Controller
{
}
```

Error im getting

HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

UPDATED QUESTION

Now i want to redirect Unauthorized users to ErrorView and Unauthenticated users to Login page. I have put my modified CustomAuthorise below. But it's not working. Pls guide me..

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (!httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;
        else 
            return true;
    }
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
        RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Error", action = "AccessDenied" }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For redirecting unauthorized users you don't need to customize `AuthorizeAttribute`. Simply in `Startup.ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)` method or your custom OWIN startup method add following line:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Error/AccessDenied"),
    });
}
```

But if you want differentiate between unauthenticated users and unauthorized. Write your custom filter like this:

```
public class MyAuthAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Error/AccessDenied");
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }        
    }
}
```

Then you could add log in url in OWIN startup method:

```
LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
```

Comment: Thank you so much again... :) Yes your solution solved it. But there is another problem also. Unauthenticated user are also redirected to the AccessDenied view with your solution. But it would be better if i can redirect them to login page. What will be the solution for it?

Comment: In this scenario you a custom filter to check your desired privilege in `AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore()` and if user logged in but not meet that page privilege return false and in `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` redirect it like this: `filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Error/AccessDenied")`

Comment: I did it as you said. But it is not working. Pls guide me. I have updated my question(UPDATED QUESTION part).

Comment: I have updated my post. But it looks like almost same as your. With just a minor change.

Comment: @ Sam Farajpour Ghamari, I applied your code and it works fine for authorization. But for an unauthenticated user it redirects to 404 error page instead of login page. In your code i can see that there is no AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore()(which you recommended to use) What will be the solution. Pls help..

Comment: No you don't need implement `AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore()`. Have you updated `ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)` login path with your own log in URL?

Comment: Could you submit updated url? and also url of redirected 404 error page.

Comment: @ Sam Farajpour Ghamari,                                                             LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),                                             url of redirected 404 error page                                                                                       http://localhost:39470/Masters/City   (City is the view im going to access from outside)

Comment: Do you see this url in the address bar of 404 error page? Have you tested that page without attribute? I think your page is not accessible even without any filter.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I can't access it even without any attribute. I noticed it now after you told me. Is there any way to correct it?

Comment: Your url is not match with your action method. Double check your controller and action names with the URL.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent and simple solution to an annoying problem. It's very confusing for users when they keep getting thrown back to the login screen with no explanation when they already are authenticated but lack role membership. Even better, I set filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Unauthorized" } with "Unauthorized" as View in the Shared folder. This preserves the URL the user was trying to reach (so they know what they are being blocked from). Using a shared view makes it accessible from anywhere.